# Unable to login using HTTP Authenticate

Tags: authentication, http

I recently moved a site to a new server and everything went very well. There is one page that requires http authentication to access it. One member group was not able to log in, so I reset the password for that member, but they are not still not able to log into the page and I am not able to log in as Super Admin either. If I remove the access restrictions I can access the page without issue.

Running EE 2.7.2 and yes there is an .htaccess file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Need more details about "not able to login"... are you getting password errors? What is happening exactly?

Comment: I get the following error: The user name or password you entered for this area on mysite.com:80 was incorrect. Make sure you’re entering them correctly, and then try again.

Comment: That is a weird error. Please post a screenshot? Where are you setting these passwords?

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. The password has an @ in it and I think that is causing it to be rejected. Would you concur?